Bcachefs: remove dead drive from an online filesystem
I'm playing around with bcachefs to see how it handles various scenarios.
Currently, I'm doing a simple experiment where I'm writing random data to a file on an array with 3 HDDs set up with 2 data replicas.
During this process I yank one of the drives, wait for everything to settle (the write stops for a moment before it realizes the drive is not there, and then continues fine) and then see what happens (and how to fix this mess afterwards).
bcachefs now prints tons of errors like:
[10258.501111] bcachefs (sda1): error writing journal entry 3494: I/O
[10259.208544] bcachefs (sda1): btree write error: I/O

My question - is there a way to remove the now non-existing drive from the array without unmounting the file system?
I assumed that it would be possible to, with the file system online, tell bcachefs to give up on that drive, rereplicate what is left and move on.
I tried the regular bcachefs device remove but the device has to be present in the system for that to work.
